# ¿Como solucionar la autenticación de inicio de sesión?

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas tardes camaradas estoy creando un login, el cual tengo los registros ya en la base de datos, el detalle que al momento de dar clic al botón de iniciar sesión, le ingreso datos falsos y como quiera me da acceso al menú principal, solo esta tomando en cuenta los capos vacíos que están validados en PHP,no se si este mal algo que me falto implementar, ya que valide la conexión por medio de Postman y esta bien, en el manifest tengo ya los permisos de internet, el cual también tengo la implementación de volley, pero no logro saber exactamente cual es el error ya que no me los arroja.

**login.php**

```
<?PHP

  require "conexion.php";

 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $pass = $_POST["pass"];

if (empty($email) || empty($pass)) {

echo "Error 1";

}else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_usuario_final WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $data = array();
    $num = $query->num_rows;

    if ($num > 0) {
        while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $resultado;
            echo json_encode($data);
      }
    }else{
        echo "Error 2";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URL_SERVIDOR ="http://192.168.2.45/LogisHuman/login.php";

EditText texcorreo,texpass;
Button btniniciar,btnregistrate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    texcorreo=findViewById(R.id.texcorreo);
    texpass=findViewById(R.id.texpass);
    btnregistrate = findViewById(R.id.btnregistrate);
    btniniciar = findViewById(R.id.btniniciar);

    btnregistrate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistroUser.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    });

   btniniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           login();
       }
   });


}

public void login(){
    StringRequest stringRequest;
    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_SERVIDOR,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("Error 1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Favor de llenar todos los campos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (response.equals("Error 2")) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "El registro no existe.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Inicio de Sesion exitoso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PrincipalActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error al iniciar sesión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("email", texcorreo.getText().toString().trim());
            param.put("pass", texpass.getText().toString().trim());

            return param;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
  }
```

Comment: No se de tu error.. pero por lo que mas quieras, encripta ese password!!!!!

Comment: Pero, es que en tu php solo validas que que estén vacíos. Al no estar vacíos no genera ningún error...